# Why does the kind of my type have '-> Constraint' at the end?

Tags: haskell, abstract-data-type

The Haskell tutorial I'm reading has a section introducing the basics of type [*kinds*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#kinds-and-some-type-foo), and describes a type class

```
class Tofu t where  
    tofu :: j a -> t a j
```

as having the kind

```
* -> (* -> *) -> *
```

I understand that, but when I enter `:k Tofu` in GHCi, I get

```
Tofu :: (* -> (* -> *) -> *) -> GHC.Prim.Constraint
```

What is `GHC.Prim.Constraint` and why does the kind of `Tofu` have this form rather than simply `* -> (* -> *) -> *`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`t` is a type parameter of the class `Tofu` of kind `* -> (* -> *) -> *` (written `t :: * -> (* -> *) -> *`). 
This is the inferred type of `t` by GHC because in the absence of `-XPolyKinds`, GHC tries to default all type parameters to kind `*`. Thus GHC assumes `a` has kind `*` (though nothing in your signature makes this the only choice).

The *type* constructor `(->)` has *kind* `* -> * -> *`. Since `j a` appears as a parameter to `(->)`, `j a` must have kind `*`. Since GHC has assumed that `a` has kind `*`, `j` is a type that takes something of kind `*` and returns something of kind `*`. Thus:

```
j :: * -> *
```

Since `t` is applied to both `a` and `j`, `t` has the kind `* -> (* -> *) -> *`, because the first argument `a` has kind `*` and the second argument `j` has kind `*->*`, and the overall type `t a j` *must* have kind `*` since it is also a parameter of the type `(->)`.

Classes are just types taking type parameters (just like `data Foo a b`), except `Foo a b` has kind `*` while `Tofu t` has kind a special kind `Constraint`. Thus the kind of `Tofu` is:

```
(* -> (* -> *) -> *) -> Constraint
```

as GHC indicates. `Constraint` is just the kind given to constraints. In the signature

```
(Num a) => a -> a -> a
```

`(Num a)` is a *type* of *kind* `Constraint`.

Comment: I almost understand, but I'm a beginner. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: It's a bit less cryptic if I look at `:t tofu`, actually. Though I'm still a bit foggy.

Comment: Thanks. I get the chain of reasoning that leads to `* -> (* -> *) -> *`. What I'm struggling with is how that fits into the bigger picture, particularly the idea that "classes take type parameters and return a `Constraint`".

Comment: Just like `(Num a)` is a constraint (corresponding to the `Num` class), `Tofu t` is  a constraint. (Fully applied) constraints like `Tofu t` have kind `Constraint`.

Comment: I think one thing (though not the only thing) that confuses me here is that the constraint seems to float free. I see that it says, roughly, that the class `Tofu` has defined (?) a constraint that (one of the types it expects?) must be of kind `* -> (* -> *) -> *`. But that understanding feels a bit shaky (for example, what if there were two arguments to `Tofu`?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Think of typeclass declarations as defining special data types (the `Constraint`s; though they are often called *dictionaries*). So your class `Tofu` defines a type `Constraint`. It has an argument `t` which has kind `* -> (* -> *) -> *` and so the type of the type-constructor `Tofu` is a function from the type of `t` to `Constraint`.  If `Tofu` had two arguments `t` and `s` you'd have that the type of `Tofu` would be "type of `t`" `->` "type of `s`" `->Constraint`, etc.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius To get a better understanding on `class` and `instance` declaration it's a good thing to know how they are translated into `Core`. `class`es becomes `data` declarations for dictionaries (or `Constraint`s if you want) while `instance`s become functions from dictionaries to dictionaries (i.e. given certain `Constraint`s (the parent classes context) they return a new `Constraint` that represent the current instance).